# Jekyll build all files to _site with no subfolders

Tags: jekyll

Currently, when my site builds, subfolders are created within the _site directory for various assets (e.g. static, uploads, etc).  I'd like to just dump all files into the top-level directory with no subfolders.  So, all the images and posts, etc, would go together into _site with no subfolder separation.  It would looks something like this:

```
_site
  - image01.jpg
  - home.html
  - 2017-05-24-sample-post.html
  - main.css
  - main.js
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the files at root level would make Jekyll generate the corresponding files in `_site` directly. There may be exceptions to this as using `permalinks` in posts, but for other files should work.

For example:

```
$ jekyll new newsite --blank
$ touch image01.jpg
$ touch home.html
$ touch 2017-05-24-sample-post.html
$ touch main.css
$ touch main.js

$ tree
.
├── 2017-05-24-sample-post.html
├── about.md
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── home.html
├── image01.jpg
├── index.md
├── main.css
├── main.js
└── _posts
    └── 2017-06-12-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown

1 directory, 11 files
$jekyll build

├── 2017-05-24-sample-post.html
├── about.md
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── home.html
├── image01.jpg
├── index.md
├── main.css
├── main.js
├── _posts
│   └── 2017-06-12-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
└── _site
    ├── 2017-05-24-sample-post.html
    ├── about
    │   └── index.html
    ├── assets
    │   └── main.css
    ├── feed.xml
    ├── home.html
    ├── image01.jpg
    ├── index.html
    ├── jekyll
    │   └── update
    │       └── 2017
    │           └── 06
    │               └── 12
    │                   └── welcome-to-jekyll.html
    ├── main.css
    └── main.js

9 directories, 21 files
```

See how the new files are created at root level.